# Create a drop-down menu in a QGIS Processing script?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I'm trying to write a QGIS processing script using the new API (3.4), but I hardly find any documentation. Based on this excellent resource by Anita Graser (https://anitagraser.com/2018/03/25/processing-script-template-for-qgis3/), I could manage to set up a basic script that mostly fits my needs.

But I have some fixed-value (eg: `['walking', 'car']`) options for which I'd like to include drop-down menus. I assume that I have to use a `QgsProcessingParameterString` but using the available documentation, I could'nt figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The PyQGIS documentation can be searched for all potential QgsProcessingParameter classes: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/search.html?q=QgsProcessingParameter&check_keywords=yes

For your use case, [QgsProcessingParameterEnum](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProcessingParameterEnum.html) seems fitting.

Here's a usage example from [qgis-latlontools-plugin](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/qgis-latlontools-plugin/blob/master/geom2field.py):

```
self.addParameter(
    QgsProcessingParameterEnum(
        self.PrmCoordinateOrder,
        tr('Coordinate order when using 1 field'),
        options=[tr('Lat,Lon (Y,X) - Google map order'),tr('Lon,Lat (X,Y) order')],
        defaultValue=0,
        optional=True)
        )
```

Comment: 'QgsProcessingParameterEnum' gives value as Integer i.e. the index. Can you tell me how to access the value from it in processing script

Comment: Open the plugin in Github, find PrmCoordinateOrder and do a check for where it is used (click on it, select references).
There is also an example with more than 2 options further down